# Fast API JSON response with Bytes

Tags: python, json, mongodb, byte, fastapi

I'm using a FAST API to retrieve a mongo document that contains some bytes. The structure is as follows

```
item = 
{"namd" : "xyz",
 "value1: b'\x89PNG\r\n\sla\..."
...
 "some_other_byte: b'\x89PNG\r\n\sla\..."  
}
```

using a post request in fast API to return the above data, it tries to convert it json, but fails to do so automatically.

So I tried this:

```
json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(item)
```

but then I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Is there a way to automatically convert the above dict into a json so it can be returned in a rest API? What would be the best way to do that?

Comment: How exactly it fails? pymongo works with bson which has some extra data types not available in json. How your model looks like?

Comment: yes exactly, is there a way to have this automatically convert? I didn't create any model in fast API. Is there a way to infer it automatically?

Comment: You can set default_factory to convert bson specific fields to json but you need to define  models to do so.

Comment: the document contains more than 100 items, so building a model seems like to be not ideal for this case

Answer (score 6):

With FastAPI `jsonable_encoder` you can use custom encoders. Example of converting arbitrary `bytes` object to base64 `str`:

```
json_compatible_item_data = jsonable_encoder(item, custom_encoder={
        bytes: lambda v: base64.b64encode(v).decode('utf-8')})
```

Decoding target fields on the client side can be done like this:

```
value1 = base64.b64decode(response_dict["value1"])
```

Comment: that's what I was looking for. thanks. How can I then reconvert it back to what it was before?

Comment: I've added a decoding example

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the `jsonable_encoder` is an unnecessary wrapper around the lambda.  I just call base64 directly on the `pyodbc` data row...

```
column_names = tuple(c[0] for c in cursor.description)
for row in cursor:
    row = [base64.b64encode(x).decode() if isinstance(x, bytes) else x for x in row]
    yield dict(zip(column_names, row))
```

But seriously, why is this necessary?  For everything else, FastAPI just works "out of the box".  This seems like a bug.